# Creating more than 1000 users at a time in new version firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to create more than 1000 users at a time by using 
createUserWithEmailAndPassword api.But after 10-15 users created successfully,I got the error message that firebase block this device due to some unusal activity.

As per my understanding,this is because,whenever i am creating user ,user automatically login due to which from a single device multiple user login,firebase blocked the user.

Will there any ways to solve this problem.Please suggest me how to create more than 1000 users.

Will there any ways to use old sdk in new sdk in firebase.In old version firebase api,it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update (2016-11-08), original answer below:

Firebase just updated their command line tools and added an `auth:import` command:

> The `auth:import` command imports user accounts into a Firebase project.

See the [reference documentation for `auth:import`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth-import) to learn more about it.

There now also is a Firebase Admin SDK, which contains functionality that you can run on a server to create user accounts without immediately signing them in. This SDK is still under a rate limiting though, so you'll probably be better served by the `auth:import` command of the CLI.

**Original answer**

The current Firebase Authentication API is made to allow users to create their own account. It is not meant to allow pre-creating accounts by some administrative process. As you've discovered, such a process will quickly be blocked.

There is no way to accomplish your use-case at the moment, aside from creating the accounts when the user actually signs up. We may expand the API in the future to allow you use-case, but as usual: no promises or timelines.

Answer (score 0):

Try to logout user after it has been successfully created and before you make call of another user creation.

Try the following code. I have not tested it but it should work. If it does not try in increase timeout delay.

```
var userArray = [
  {
    email: "...",
    password: "..."
  },
  ...
];
createUser(userArray, 0);

function createUser(array, index){
  if (index >= array.length){
    return;
  }
  var user = array[index];
  firebase.auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
         firebase.auth().signOut().then(function(){
           // Call to create new user
           createUser(array, index + 1);
         });
      }, 100);
    });
}
```

#### [Updated]

I think firebase does not allow to be signed in with multiple users so when you call `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword` it should replace existing user with new one.

Try to set an observer on current user and see if it changes when you call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

For more info about managing the users check the following link.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: Thanks for replying,but it will logout the current user,not the current created user.

Comment: Actually when you first call `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword` this will replace current user with new one. I am not 100% sure but I think firebase does not allow to be signed in with multiple accounts. It has method `firebase.auth().currentUser;` which returns ONE user.

Comment: user is changing with the newly created user.

Comment: That's what I though. Have you tried the whole code from my answer?

Comment: yeah,but the same problem

Comment: Maybe increasing timeout will help but if not read answer bellow by Frank.